# Open vSwitch bridge is not working with Separate Network Namespace

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, switch

I'm trying to configure and set up Open vSwitch using separate network namespace. My target is to add two interfaces in the same separate network namespace (like my created namespace "netns-ovs") and I am trying to forward packets from a2 interface to b2 interface using open vSwitch. To clear the target figure is attached.

I'm getting the following error when trying to up the bridge in the separate network namespace:

```
root@student:~# sudo ip netns exec netns-ovs ovs-vsctl show
72fd2b3a-388b-4a44-818b-5d27f855e5c0
    Bridge "ovsbr0"
        Port "b2"
            Interface "b2"
        Port "ovsbr0"
            Interface "ovsbr0"
                type: internal
        Port "a2"
            Interface "a2"
    ovs_version: "2.0.2"
root@student:~# sudo ip netns exec netns-ovs ovs-ofctl show ovsbr0
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:00001af89191ab45
n_tables:254, n_buffers:256
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
actions: OUTPUT SET_VLAN_VID SET_VLAN_PCP STRIP_VLAN SET_DL_SRC SET_DL_DST SET_NW_SRC SET_NW_DST SET_NW_TOS SET_TP_SRC SET_TP_DST ENQUEUE
 LOCAL(ovsbr0): addr:3e:d7:2f:6c:e7:46
     config:     PORT_DOWN
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x4): frags=normal miss_send_len=0
root@student:~# sudo ip netns exec netns-ovs ifconfig ovsbr0 up
ovsbr0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Is it possible or not please?
[image: Target of Task]